# custom progress bar modification challenge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am trying a make a progress bar as seen in the below image.

What I am unable to do is to:

- draw a connecting line between numbers
- active number will have a bigger circle
- completed steps will have a green line and uncompleted with gray line.

[Custom progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM9q4.png)

**css**

```
.custom-progress-bar ul li span {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #cbcbcb;
    color:#fff;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 14px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;

}
.custom-progress-bar ul {

    list-style:none;
}

.custom-progress-bar .last{
width: 80px;
border-radius: 20px;
}

.custom-progress-bar .completed{
    background: #9cc656;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="custom-progress-bar">
                    <ul>
                    <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">1</a></span></li>
                    <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">2</a></span></li>
                    <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">3</a></span></li>
                    <li><span class="bubble completed"><a href="#">4</a></span></li>
                    <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">5</a></span></li>
                    <li><span class="bubble last"><a href="#">finish</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this code:

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
}
.custom-progress-bar ul li span {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #cbcbcb;
    color:#fff;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.custom-progress-bar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.custom-progress-bar .last {
width: 80px;
border-radius: 20px;
}

.custom-progress-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
}

.custom-progress-bar ul li::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: #cbcbcb;
}

.custom-progress-bar ul li:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed {
  margin-right: 2px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(156,198,86,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(156,198,86,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(156,198,86,1);
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed::after {
     margin-left: -24px;
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed + li span {
    background: #9cc656;
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed + li + li span {
    background: #9cc656;
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed + li::after {
    background: #9cc656;
}

.custom-progress-bar li.completed + li + li::after {
    background: #9cc656;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-progress-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">1</a></span></li>
        <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">2</a></span></li>
        <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">3</a></span></li>
        <li class="completed"><span class="bubble"><a href="#">4</a></span></li>
        <li><span class="bubble"><a href="#">5</a></span></li>
        <li><span class="bubble last"><a href="#">finish</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```